# Angular 2-5 - ngfor without wrapping in a div container

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, html, ngfor

I have putted ngFor in a div which display my object containing HTML and that is coming from my array collection. But I don't want that my object, containing html node (HTMLElement) should be wrapped in a div, but it is should be displayed with out the div ,in which I have putted my **ngFor** Directive.

*Here is my html*

```
<div *ngFor="let mt of mappingTable"  [innerHTML]="mt?.htmlElement.outerHTML  | escapeHtml: 'html'  ">
 </div>
```

with inner `[innerHTML]`, it is okay but in the output I see the  htmlElement.outerHTML is wrapped in a div.

I have tried `<ng-container>` but that display raw html on the web-page

Comment: Could you add some code examples to make it better understandable to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user `[outerHTML]` instead of `[innerHTML]` if you do not want to wrap your html inside any parent html element:

`<div *ngFor="let mt of mappingTable"  [outerHTML]="mt?.htmlElement.outerHTML  |escapeHtml: 'html'  ">
 </div>`

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for are [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). `ng-container` does exactly what you want, you can use it for your `ngFor`but it won't be put in the DOM by Angular.

Comment: I used ng-container but that only display my raw HTML on web page.
any other way ?